# Problem in merging images

Tags: beamer

I have five images, want to show first image1 on frame 1-> then press enter or click then->image2 appears on same frame....till 5th image5

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{image of txs}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  \only<1>{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{images/ps1.png}}
  \only<1>{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{images/ps2.png}}
\only<1>{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{images/ps3.png}}
  \only<1>{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{images/ps4.png}}
\only<1>{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{images/ps5.png}}

 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which package i shouls use? In first image, i have empty boxs in second have A B C,so that after overlapping , boxes fill with content.

Comment: It's not a question of which package. Beamer is sufficient. You just need to fix the overlay specifications and maybe use something other than `\only`. Right now, you are showing every image on the first slide of the frame and no other. Maybe you want `\only<2>`, `\only<3>`, `\only<4>` and `\only<5>` for images 2-5? But more likely you want overlay specifications such as `<1->`, `<2->` etc. Without code we can compile to test it is hard to help, but you will need to undo the spacing the first 4 images take if they are supposed to overlap. Can you provide the code for the images?

Comment: Or if you can't provide the code for the images, you can `\includegraphics{example-image}` and `{example-image-a}` and `-b` and `-c`.  We all have those automatically.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you after something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{image of txs}
    \begin{center}
\setkeys{Gin}{height=5cm}
\only<1>{\includegraphics{example-image}}%{images/ps1.png}}
\only<2>{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}%{images/ps2.png}}
\only<3>{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}%{images/ps3.png}}
\only<4>{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}%{images/ps4.png}}
\only<5>{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}%{images/ps5.png}}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly, the `setkeys` is passing `height=5cm` to all of the `includegraphics`, but how?  Or perhaps more relevantly, how would I find out that `Gin` is the correct first argument?

Comment: (+1) though I'm not sure this is what the OP wants. (As in: I really don't know and couldn't decide between 2 interpretations, hence a binary answer.) @Teepeemm page 14 of `graphicx` manual? (Section on globally setting keys.)

Comment: @cfr, me either not sure what OP means with "merging" images.  +1 for your nice answer!

Comment: I must remember that technique with `\setkeys`. That's very neat.

Comment: Still all images are appearing on different frames. At end of all images, i  am not getting combine form of all images.

Comment: @saralee, sorry, your question is unclear. Images are in one frame, but they use five slides (1/1, 1/2, ... 1/5). Only on this way is possible to put your image with size of 5cm height in frame. If you like to have all images on one slike, than please edit your question, what you after and how big are your images actually.

Comment: Size would not be issue, because first i create single frame with all five images with proper gap .Then remove four images and save it image1. Save five images individually. Now overlapping will be accurate.

Comment: Please, edit your question. Other people will not see your comments. BTW, from your comment I'm not able to figured out what you are after. Please provide a sketch, how the images should be arranged in frame

Comment: @saralee The images in my answer overlap. If that's not what you mean by their overlapping, you need to explain what you want. I had 2 possible interpretations: an overlapping version and a one-after-the-other version (similar to Zarko's but more boring without a duck). But if even the overlapping version is wrong, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @cfr, me too (out of ideas). Hopefully OP will edit question and clarify what (s)he is after.

Answer (score 3):

Without code for the pictures (or some equivalent), it isn't possible to test this properly. The following assumes that all 5 images have the same dimensions. If this is false, you would need to adjust the horizontal and/or vertical spacing to align things correctly.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{image of txs}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item 
    \raisebox{-25mm}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702887/
      \includegraphics<1->[height=5cm]{images/ps1.png}%
      \smash[c]{\llap{\includegraphics<2->[height=5cm]{images/ps2.png}}}%
      \smash[c]{\llap{\includegraphics<3->[height=5cm]{images/ps3.png}}}%
      \smash[c]{\llap{\includegraphics<4->[height=5cm]{images/ps4.png}}}%
      \smash[c]{\llap{\includegraphics<5->[height=5cm]{images/ps5.png}}}}    
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: overlapping draft images]

This overlays/overlaps the images rather than replacing them. If you want replacement, you don't need the `\smash` or `\llap` at all. In the case, you can just delete the hyphens from the overlay specifications to implement sequential use.

```
    \raisebox{-25mm}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702887/
      \includegraphics<1>[height=5cm]{images/ps1.png}%
      \includegraphics<2>[height=5cm]{images/ps2.png}%
      \includegraphics<3>[height=5cm]{images/ps3.png}%
      \includegraphics<4>[height=5cm]{images/ps4.png}%
      \includegraphics<5>[height=5cm]{images/ps5.png}}
```

Note that `\includegraphics` is itself 'overlay-aware' in Beamer and you can configure an overlay specification directly rather than needling a command such as `\only`, at least in simple cases.

[image: sequential images]

Answer (score 2):

Beamer makes `\includegraphics` overlay aware, this means you don't have to wrap it into the `\only` macro, you can simply use `\includegraphics<...>{...}` to specify on which overlay the image should be visible.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{image of txs}
  \includegraphics<1->[height=1cm]{example-image-a}%
  \includegraphics<2->[height=1cm]{example-image-b}%
  \includegraphics<3->[height=1cm]{example-image-c}%
  \includegraphics<4->[height=1cm]{example-image}%
  \includegraphics<5->[height=1cm]{example-image-duck}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I already pointed out ;).